# Can't send image to Pinterest popup form

Tags: image, pinterest

This is a bit complicated but I've got an image which uses the Pinterest parameter in its anchor entity, with the Pinterest button appearing elsewhere in the page:

`<a id="im_popup" class="cloud-zoom" pi:pinit:media="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatchmybag.com%2Fshop%2Fbags%2Fbespoke-clutch%26media=http%3A%2F%2Fmatchmybag.com%2Fimage%2Fcache%2Fdata%2Fbags%2Fdesign-a-bag%2FThe-Clutch%2FCD1_fr_xlsq-467x467.jpg" title="" onclick="" rel="position: 'inside'" href="image/paps/linked/243241_colour_silvercrest.jpg" style="position: relative; display: block;">`

The image in the 'media' parameter is not the same as the one in the img entity - just using it for testing for now but will change it to a dynamically set URL later.

When I click on the Pinterest button, the pop-up form appears and contains the correct description text, but the preview image is blank and when I click 'Pin It' in the popup form I get the 'This is not a valid image.' message.

The URL appearing in the Pinterest popup form is as follows:

http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatchmybag.com%2Fbespoke-clutch&media=http%3A%2F%2Fpinterest.com%2Fpin%2Fcreate%2Fbutton%2F%3Furl%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fmatchmybag.com%2Fshop%2Fbags%2Fbespoke-clutch%26media%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fmatchmybag.com%2Fimage%2Fcache%2Fdata%2Fbags%2Fdesign-a-bag%2FThe-Clutch%2FCD1_fr_xlsq-467x467.jpg&description=Bespoke%20Clutch&layout=

Can anyone see what the problem is here? I've spent more hours than I'd care to admit to on this and would be so grateful for some pointers. Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Pinterest is very strict about showing only images that actually appear on the web site. So maybe that is the issue, right now I cannot see that image on the web site provided in the `url` parameter (but then the question is quite old already...)